# ViewController not released from Memory

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

I have this view hierarchy

- > RouterDashboardViewController : RootViewController
- > RootViewController : UIViewController

Currently, RouterDashboardViewController instance is in the navigation stack. When I reset rootViewController of NavigationController then RouerDashboardInstance still exist in memory because I can check my `deinit{}` method not gets called.Below are the stack traces in Instruments but am not able to detect any reason why my RouterDashboard instance not get deallocated. I am sure there will be retain cycles which keeps RouterDashboard instance still alive. One more thing am not understanding these stack traces because ViewDidLoad() method called several times.[image: Stack Traces of Instruments]

Comment: Show you code. viewDidLoad Method at least.

Comment: @CaptainAlina There are lot of code in viewDidLoad method,you may not understand.

Comment: @CaptainAlina But i already makes my delegate var weak

Comment: If You don't show Your code people won't be able to help. It's up to You.

Comment: Don’t forget you can view the memory graph to see which objects are retaining it. That might give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Something has a strong reference to `RouterDashboardViewController`.  A few things to check…

- Are you assigning it to a variable?

  - You may need to declare it as `weak var …`
- Is it a delegate of another class?

  - Make sure delegate properties are also `weak var`s
- Does it use any closures that refer it `self`?

  - Add a capture list to your closure's parameter list (`[unowned self]` or `[weak self]` )

Comment: @ Ashley I tried all the above things but still not able to find.